# Weird effect whislt applying imperfections

Tags: texturing, glass

[image]
I was trying to make a bottle for a project and decided to add some pretty basic imperfections. I tried some maps and then with a musgrave texture but the result is the same. Any ideas on why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: are you talking about the triangulation effect? maybe check into Object Data > Geometry > click on Clear Custom Split Normals Data?

Comment: @moonboots Yes, I have checked but I since I didint add any of those, I cannot remove any, only add.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, could you please share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: It also can be Z-fighting. Are you sure you don't have an extra object visible in Render (may be hidden in viewport)?

Comment: @FFeller was right, no idea why but there were 3 bottles in the scene. Deleted 2 and now it works, thank you both!